# Can two processes with same compile time options have different byte alignments on same machine?

Tags: c, powerpc

I have a process which writes into a shared memory and another process which reads from it. Both share the same header file and also have same compiler flags used for compilation. While running both the processes, the structures are 4 byte aligned in one and 8 byte aligned in another.

Is this possible? If yes, then any solution to have same alignment in both?

eg. One of the structure is

```
typedef struct a {
                   unsigned int x;
                   unsigned long long y;
                 }b;
```

In process 1 the sizeof above structure is 12 whereas in process 2 the size is 16. Size of int is 4 bytes and unsigned long long is 8 bytes in the machine.

In gdb the data stored in shared memory starting from the instance of above structure looks like:

```
0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08
```

In process 1: `b.x = 0x1020304` and `b.y = 0x0`
In process 2: `b.x = 0x1020304` and `b.y = 0x5060708`

Comment: Can you add more information? What OS and compiler? Also, the source of the structure definition and debugger output showing the different structures in the separate processes would be helpful.

Comment: @Andrew: I have added one structure.I am using PowerPc for execution of process and compiling the code on a fedora machine using cross compiler for powerpc

Comment: Still need more information. How are you determining that the structures have different alignment in the different processes? Show us that data.

Comment: @Andrew :I have added a sample data

Comment: Can you show the output of the gdb command `ptype b` from each process?

Comment: The output of pt b is same in both the cases. It shows unsigned int for x and unsigned long long for y.

Comment: It is possible that you have a synchronization problem and not an alignment issue (e.g. that the reading process is reading the data before the writer writes it). A minimal compilable example would help.

Comment: @AndrewMedico : No, it cannot be a synchronization problem. The reading process reads it much after the writer process writes in it.

Comment: It could be a synchronization problem. If the reader code doesn't know about the writer (and when it has made changes), the reader might fetch the value from the shared memory into a register only once and never re-read the shared memory. Check the generated assembly.

Comment: "In process 1 the sizeof above structure is 12 whereas in process 2 the size is 16."  I doubt this.  Show the evidence to support this claim.

Answer (score 1):

In order to align the structure, take a look at the [align](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) attribute (GCC specific). 
As for your question, I don't know see any reason why the compiler is aligning the structures differently. You'd have to provide more details in order to investigate that...

Comment: I have added more details